# Android studio can't support version 4.4.4

Tags: android, sdk

I have a problem with android studio SDK. I know that API 19 supports all versions 4.4+ [Android 4.4 APIS](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) , but my application cannot support android version 4.4.4 . And you can see on the image

[image: My SDK installations]

I have already installed the API 19 , but still not working.
Same is and for the android 5.0.2 version.

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bemoir">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />


<application
    android:name="com.bemoir.crash.reports.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon120"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/RegisterTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/RegisterTheme"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.AvatarAndMemoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.QrScanner"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.NfcScanner"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.NfcReader"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.ScannActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.SelectCategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.FeedDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.TermsFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.PrivacyFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.bemoir.crash.reports.ReportActivity"
        android:label="ReportActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:process=":report_process"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.bemoir.crash.reports.ReportFilesProvider"
        android:authorities="com.bemoir"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":report_process"
        tools:ignore="ExportedContentProvider" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="7f35f2b1a4562e9730075cba932d9c83585f128e" />

</application>
```

Comment: Explain what is the problem exactly, how do you know that it cannot support android version 4.4.4? Does it crush, or what? Use http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ if your English is not fluent enough.

Comment: It's doesn't crush ! The application cannot be installed to mobile device with android version 4.4.4 . If I go to Google Play Store and try to search my application , the answer is " No results found " . But if I go from other link (from the web link of the application) then the application is shown in Google Play Store but I can't install it ( I quote : " Your device isn't compatible with this version. )

Comment: That doesn't mean that it is not compatible with 4.4.4. It isn't compatible with your device only. Share a link to your app, and I'll check it. I have 3 devices with 4.4.4 in my hands currently.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bemoir&hl=en

Comment: Looks like it uses some specific feature, which is not present in all devices. It is not compatible with some 4.0 and 4.1.2 devices that I have. But so far I don't know what is wrong exactly. You can add your manifest file, where all restrictions are defined into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it looks clear. Your manifest contains

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />
```

Which rejects app from being installed on devices which don't have NFC.

Comment: Are you sure , because if I ran the application from my studio to mobile device without NFC and it was installed successful with no problems . But may the installation problem be from the .apk file ?

Comment: @LubomirBabev, can't you try installing the APK file yourself? What I'm sure is that google play won't allow to install such application on such device. `android:required="true"` means that the feature (NFC in you case) is required, and the app shouldn't show for devices not having this feature.

Comment: I try to find the application in Google Play Store with mobile device without NFC and I can't find it, so by my opinion your answer is correct. If I change the **android:required="true"** with **android:required="false"** will the application be compatible for those devices ?

Comment: @LubomirBabev, yes, it will be. But you will have to check NFC availability in your application manually before using NFC, or you'll get exceptions